# Making changes to factor levels but keeping the same order of the levels

Tags: r, r-factor

I have the following data frame:

```
df <- structure(list(group1 = structure(c(2L, 8L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 
                                          9L, 6L, 3L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 9L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 
                                          9L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 9L, 8L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 8L, 9L), .Label = c("NEW ENGLAND",
                                          "MIDDLE ATLANTIC", "E. NOR. CENTRAL", "W. NOR. CENTRAL", "SOUTH ATLANTIC",
                                          "E. SOU. CENTRAL", "W. SOU. CENTRAL", "MOUNTAIN", "PACIFIC"), class = "factor"), 
                     Sample_Size_group1 = c(220L, 157L, 372L, 331L, 127L, 135L, 
                                            196L, 267L, 135L, 331L, 267L, 196L, 157L, 127L, 372L, 127L, 
                                            267L, 135L, 196L, 157L, 372L, 196L, 157L, 267L, 372L, 135L, 
                                            196L, 135L, 267L, 157L, 267L, 196L, 157L, 267L, 157L, 267L), 
                     group2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                                          2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
                                          4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L), .Label = c("NEW ENGLAND", 
                                          "MIDDLE ATLANTIC", "E. NOR. CENTRAL", "W. NOR. CENTRAL", 
                                          "SOUTH ATLANTIC", "E. SOU. CENTRAL", "W. SOU. CENTRAL", "MOUNTAIN", 
                                          "PACIFIC"), class = "factor"),
                     Sample_Size_group2 = c(120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 220L, 220L, 220L, 
                                            220L, 220L, 220L, 220L, 331L, 331L, 331L, 331L, 331L, 331L, 
                                            127L, 127L, 127L, 127L, 127L, 372L, 372L, 372L, 372L, 135L, 
                                            135L, 135L, 196L, 196L, 157L)), .Names = c("group1", "Sample_Size_group1", 
                                            "group2", "Sample_Size_group2"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
                                            5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 46L, 47L, 
                                            48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 
                                            91L, 92L, 93L, 100L, 101L, 106L), class = "data.frame")
```

Both of `group1` and `group2` variables have the same factor levels in the same order (note though that not all levels show up in either variable):

```
levels(df$group1)
[1] "NEW ENGLAND"     "MIDDLE ATLANTIC" "E. NOR. CENTRAL" "W. NOR. CENTRAL" "SOUTH ATLANTIC"  "E. SOU. CENTRAL"
[7] "W. SOU. CENTRAL" "MOUNTAIN"        "PACIFIC" 
levels(df$group2)
[1] "NEW ENGLAND"     "MIDDLE ATLANTIC" "E. NOR. CENTRAL" "W. NOR. CENTRAL" "SOUTH ATLANTIC"  "E. SOU. CENTRAL"
[7] "W. SOU. CENTRAL" "MOUNTAIN"        "PACIFIC"
```

I'd like to make a change to the levels for both factors by combining them with their respective sample sizes, like so:

```
df$newgroup1 <- paste0(df$group1, " (n=", df$Sample_Size_group1, ")")
df$newgroup2 <- paste0(df$group2, " (n=", df$Sample_Size_group2, ")")
```

This creates character vectors, so I'd like to turn them to factor:

```
df$newgroup1 <- factor(df$newgroup1)
df$newgroup2 <- factor(df$newgroup2)
```

But now the factor levels are no longer the same, nor are they in the original order.

```
levels(df$newgroup1)
[1] "E. NOR. CENTRAL (n=331)" "E. SOU. CENTRAL (n=135)" "MIDDLE ATLANTIC (n=220)" "MOUNTAIN (n=157)"       
[5] "PACIFIC (n=267)"         "SOUTH ATLANTIC (n=372)"  "W. NOR. CENTRAL (n=127)" "W. SOU. CENTRAL (n=196)"
levels(df$newgroup2)
[1] "E. NOR. CENTRAL (n=331)" "E. SOU. CENTRAL (n=135)" "MIDDLE ATLANTIC (n=220)" "MOUNTAIN (n=157)"       
[5] "NEW ENGLAND (n=120)"     "SOUTH ATLANTIC (n=372)"  "W. NOR. CENTRAL (n=127)" "W. SOU. CENTRAL (n=196)"
```

Here are how I would like the levels for both vectors:

```
[1] "NEW ENGLAND (n=120)"     "MIDDLE ATLANTIC (n=220)" "E. NOR. CENTRAL (n=135)" "W. NOR. CENTRAL (n=127)" 
[5] "SOUTH ATLANTIC (n=372)"  "E. SOU. CENTRAL (n=135)" "W. SOU. CENTRAL (n=196)" "MOUNTAIN (n=157)"
[9] "PACIFIC (n=267)"
```

I know I can do this manually easily enough, especially with a package like `forcats`, but how could I apply this programmatically in base `R`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `grep` to match original level to the new unique elements. After that, sort elements by index to create the new level.

```
# Create newgroup1 and newgroup2
df$newgroup1 <- paste0(df$group1, " (n=", df$Sample_Size_group1, ")")
df$newgroup2 <- paste0(df$group2, " (n=", df$Sample_Size_group2, ")")

# Get the level
LEV <- levels(df$group1)

# Find the unique element in newgroup1 and newgroup2
New_element <- unique(c(df$newgroup1, df$newgroup2))

# Find the index using grep
index <- sapply(LEV, grep, x = New_element)

# Use New_element[index] to set new level
df$newgroup1 <- factor(df$newgroup1, levels = New_element[index])
df$newgroup2 <- factor(df$newgroup2, levels = New_element[index])

# Check the results
levels(df$newgroup1)
levels(df$newgroup2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `unique` to line the levels up next to each other, sort by the original factor and then use that ordering to define the new factor:

```
group1_levels = unique(df[, c("group1", "newgroup1")])
group1_levels = group1_levels[order(group1_levels$group1), ]

df$newgroup1 = factor(df$newgroup1, levels = group1_levels$newgroup1)

group2_levels = unique(df[, c("group2", "newgroup2")])
group2_levels = group2_levels[order(group2_levels$group2), ]

df$newgroup2 = factor(df$newgroup2, levels = group2_levels$newgroup2)
```

Comment: That didn't work for me. Nonetheless, @ycw's solution worked. Thanks for your time!